# Remove empty lines from hive query output I am saving on local filesystem

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I am running a python script on my devbox to remotely ssh on a grid gateway box to launch another python script which runs the hive query and returns the output back and I save it on my devbox in the datestamp.tsv format.

There are some queries for which I have to run a for loop for two clusters. The problem is the output is getting saved but there are empty lines and I want the datestamp to be after the query output. This is the output I have right now -

```
2014_03_28 PT 588.12    396.73

2014_03_28 DB 0.17      0.0
```

There is an empty line after every time the query is run in for loop.

How do i remove the empty line? and put the datestamp in the last. The output format i want it to be in-

```
PT 588.12    396.73 2014_03_28
DB 0.17      0.0  2014_03_28
```

parent script:

```
def get_compute_resources():
  global output
  ensure_directory(pipeline_name, user, star_date, "daily_compute_resources")
  for grid in grids:
    cmd = 'ssh -2 -i /home/abcd/.ssh/id_dsa -l abcd -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no hostname "python2.6 /homes/abcd/starling/fetch_daily_user_summary.py -u ' + user + ' -g ' + grid + ' -d ' + starling_date + '" >> /home/abcd/projects/starling/daily_compute_resources/'+ pipeline_name +'/'+ user +'/'+ starling_date +'.tsv'
    resources = make_call(cmd).rstrip()
    print resources
```

Remote machine script:

```
cmd = "/home/y/bin/hive -e 'use star; SELECT ROUND(SUM((map_slot_seconds)/3600/24/2),2), ROUND(SUM((reduce_slots_seconds)/3600/24/2),2) from starling_job_summary where user=%s and grid=%s and dt like %s group by dt;' -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=unfunded -hiveconf mapred.reduce.tasks=1" % (user, grid, date)
  resources = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
  output = output_date+' '+output_grid+' '+resources
  print output
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually log the information?

Comment: @DarinDouglass - I edited the question with parent and remote scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It assumes you have the data you provided as a file called input.txt in the same directory that you execute the python, and gives you the data in the format desired to an output.txt file. The `if line.strip()` check will just ignore lines that are entirely whitespace, and other than that the only thing somewhat cool here is the maxsplit parameter to split() which separates the date from the rest of the line.

```
infile = 'input.txt'
outfile = 'output.txt'

with open(infile) as f:
    with open(outfile, mode='w') as output:
        data = f.readlines()
        for line in data:
            if line.strip():
                date, rest = line.split(maxsplit=1)
                date = date.strip()
                rest = rest.strip()
                output.write(rest + ' ' + date + "\n")
```

It might be possible to somewhat clean up the whitespace handling, but this was more straightforward.

Output:

```
PT 588.12    396.73 2014_03_28
DB 0.17      0.0 2014_03_28
```

Comment: This seems like adding an extra step of processing and creating one more file, which i dont want. I just edited my question to reflect the script i have in place - @Decency

Answer (score 0):

The extra white space may come from leading or trailing newlines on `output_date` and `resources` respectively. Give this a try:

```
print '{date} {grid} {res}'.format(date=output_date.strip(),
                                   grid=grid,
                                   res=resources.strip())
```

As a general comment: using `str.format` is the conventional way to create strings with variable data. You do something like it in the child script using the `%` syntax, but you could improve the readability of your parent script with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your `print` statements so they end with a comma:

```
print output,
```

From [the official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print):

> A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement
>   ends with a comma